# Filter items for update [SQL]

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to update the lost fee of all items published before the year 2000.

```
update Item
where PubYear < 2000
set LostFee = (LostFee)*1.10;
```

I tried that but its not right, how would I filter things when updating stuff?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
update Item
set LostFee = (LostFee)*1.10;
where PubYear < 2000
```

`WHERE` clause comes after `SET`

Answer (score 1):

Write you query as below:

```
update Item
set LostFee = (LostFee)*1.10 where PubYear < 2000;
```